# Почему атрибут элемента отображается с запаздыванием (при 2ой итерации показывается 1ый вариант)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

Есть сайт на `wordpress` и [таблица `wpDataTables`](https://wpdatatables.com/) с фильтром `select` с выбором по городам.

Хочу в переменной получать название городов для последующего вывода на странице, но почему-то сталкиваюсь с невозможностью получить атрибут элемента `title` на первой итерации.

**custom.js**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  wpDataTables.table_1.addOnDrawCallback(
  function(){
    var newcity = jQuery('#table_1_1_filter_sections button.dropdown-toggle').attr('title');
    var city = jQuery('#table_1_1_filter button.dropdown-toggle')[0];
    console.log(newcity,city);
});
```

UPD: Вот что удалось обнаружить - код

```
var newcity = jQuery('#table_1_1_filter_sections button.dropdown-toggle').attr('title');
```

работает, но запаздывает с итерацией, т.е. при первом выборе города считывает пустоту, а при выборе следующего - отображает предыдущее значение и так далее.

А забавное то, что **city** уже сразу в консоли вот в таком виде.

```
<button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" 
data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" title="Кемерово" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="filter-option pull-left">Кемерово</span>&nbsp;
<span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span>
</button>
```

Какие могут быть мысли?

Comment: Что за переменная `newc`?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko описался, переменная `city`

Comment: var newcity = jQuery('#table_1_1_filter_sections .dropdown-toggle').attr('title');

Comment: @Paul Wall `button.dropdown-toggle` или `.dropdown-toggle` - разницы нет, в обоих случаях ничего не выводит

Comment: @Вася не будет работать, замени на data-title и обращайся по data('title')

Comment: @Paul Wall я не могу менять вывод кода плагина. Вы хотите сказать, что не возможно обратиться к `title` элемента?

Comment: А где разметка `#table_1_1_filter button.dropdown-toggle`?

Comment: @Вася для дива нельзя, для button скорее всего тоже

Comment: в чём проблема использовать тот же `attr` что выше вместо `getAttribute` ?

Comment: @webDev_ проблема в том, что ничего не вы водит, показал, что ни с помощью методов `javascript`, ни с методами `jquery` не выходит. Не могу понять почему..

Comment: @Вася предоставьте полный код `HTML` с помощью редактирования вопроса

Comment: @webDev_ предоставил

Comment: даже делаю так
`var newc = jQuery('#table_1_1_filter button.dropdown-toggle .filter-option')[0];`

выводится:
`<span class="filter-option pull-left">Москва</span>`

Но, затем я не могу получить даже текст из `span`

`var title1 = newc.textContent;
var title2 = newc.innerHTML;
var title3 = newc.text();
console.log(title1,title2,title3);`

Comment: какая у вас версия jquery?

Comment: @Vladimir проблема не в `jquery`, а в том, что плагин при поиске посылает ajax запрос на сервер и возвращает данные, потому и не работает DOM, хотя в переменную значения я отлавливаю

Comment: @webDev_ раз объект переменной не в `dom`, то нужно с `dropdown-toggle` работать как со строковой переменной и вытащить из нее то что находится в `title`

Answer (score 1):

Получаем атрибут `title`

**Javascript:**

```js
var el = document.getElementById('test').getAttribute('title');
console.log(el);
// output Test button
```

```html
<button id="test" title="Test button">Click me</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```js
var el = $('#test').prop('title');
console.log(el);
// output Test button
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test" title="Test button">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если придерживаться коду выше, как видно в консоли - всё работает.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  let city = jQuery("#table_1_1_filter button.dropdown-toggle").attr("title");
  console.log(city);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wpDataTableFilterSection" id="table_1_1_filter_sections">
  <label>Город:</label>
  <div id="table_1_1_filter" class="column-город"><span class="filter_column filter_select" data-filter_type="selectbox" data-index="1"><div class="btn-group bootstrap-select wdt-select-filter wdt-filter-control dropup"><button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" title="Белгород" aria-expanded="false"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Белгород</span>&nbsp;
    <span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox" x-placement="bottom-start" style="max-height: 178.6px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 20px; position: absolute; transform: translate3d(0px, 42px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
      <div class="bs-searchbox" style="display: none;"><input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search..." role="textbox" aria-label="Search"></div>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" style="max-height: 160.6px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 2px;">
        <li data-original-index="0" class="active"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="text"> </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
        <li data-original-index="10"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">Кемерово</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
        <li data-original-index="17"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">Москва</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
        <li data-original-index="18"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">Мурманск</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
        <li data-original-index="33"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">Сочи</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <select class="wdt-select-filter wdt-filter-control selectpicker" title="" data-index="1" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search..." tabindex="-8">
      <option value=""> </option>
      <option value="%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE">Кемерово</option>
      <option value="%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0">Москва</option>
      <option value="%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA">Мурманск</option>
      <option value="%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8">Сочи</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Причину нашел, но как обойти не знаю: "Плагин при поиске посылает ajax запрос на сервер и возвращает данные, потому и не работает DOM", хотя в переменную-то я отлавливаю сам код..

Comment: @Вася как можно заметить по названию `addOnDrawCallback`, вызывается она после прорисовки (то есть добавления элементов в `DOM`). Заметьте, что в моём ответе `addOnDrawCallback` отсутствует. Не забудьте его вернуть при копировании.

Comment: да, `addOnDrawCallback` не работает в `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` и поэтому такое решение не может мне помочь..

Comment: появилось кое-что новенькое, изменил вопрос - посмотрите?

Answer (score 0):

Не нашел ничего лучше, как установить задержку на 0,5сек. По крайней мере работает

```
setTimeout(function() { 
city = jQuery('#table_1_1_filter button.dropdown-toggle').attr("title"); jQuery('.city').text("г. "+city); }, 500);
```